# PHPUnit: Proper pattern for failing on missing tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have looked for a native solution, to get PHPUnit to fail when it encounters a method in the target class/object which it does not have a defined test for. I have, thus far, not been able to find a way to do this.

In the meantime, the solution I have rolled myself is to include the following test at the top of all of my test classes:

```
public function test_MethodCoverage ()
{
    $Class = new ReflectionClass($this->_className);
    $methods = $Class->getMethods();

    foreach ( $methods AS $v ) {
        $this->assertTrue(
            method_exists( $this, 'test'.ucfirst($v->name) ),
            'Test for method '. $v->name .' does not exist'
        );
    }
}
```

Note: `$this->_className` is a property created in `setUp()` which contains the target class path.

I am wondering, is there a more appropriate/native way to accomplish this functionality without doing it manually?

Thanks

Comment: Usually your CI framework (eg Jenkins) takes care of that with an analysis of your code coverage. I don't think there is a `native` solution.

Comment: @colburton Thanks. We're not currently managing stuff in a CI pipeline. Something we're looking into. Thanks again.

Comment: To be on the save side you need to work with code coverage. Not having that I think your solution is all you can do.

Comment: The major PHP IDEs can generate a code coverage report for you and highlight uncovered methods in the source view.  While it's admirable to want to make sure everything is covered, there are occasionally good reasons for not covering a particular segment of code so forcing 100% code coverage might not be such a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution very good if you want all methods have test. But some private methods must be tested undirectly so you should use code coverage tools to analyze which methods tested and which methods not tested.

Use of phpunit code coverabe tool is very simple. For example:

```
phpunit --coverage-html ./report BankAccountTest
```

Source: http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/code-coverage-analysis.html